# Advertisement on the ethereum stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I have run across [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/3103/xavier-lepr%C3%AAtre-b9lab) user that has a link to a series of online [courses](https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/B9lab/ETH-3/2016-3/about) in his profile and have seen him post it in some of his comments, and also a question linking to a supposed solution on that site.

At fist glance, registration and course materials are not free (the course is 995 pounds).

Should we allow advertising through the stackexchange platform?

Comment: Please point to such comments.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8289/forking-example-ethereum-101 This one question I've seen pointing to the same site. I did not bookmark the respective questions where the comments were posted but remember seeing them on Monday). The asker did not update the question with the required information to make it answerable but the user I'm mentioning answered it anyway :)

Comment: Well the question was put on hold by the community already. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackExchange has this covered and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion has guidelines about this.

Here's the introduction:

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it
>   as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen
>   to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must*
>   disclose your affiliation in your answers.

The conclusion is:

> If the *only* reason you're here is to sell something or drive traffic
>   to your site, then please avoid posting answers...